# Only Numbers, dots, comma and slash

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will accept as values only the following

```
1
1.1
.1
1,1
,1
1/1
11
111
1111
and so on...
```

or else: A number that may be followed by a dot OR a comma OR a slash and a number at the end.

```
\d*(?:\.|\,|\/)\d
```

using this regex I only capture the 1.1 .1 1,1 ,1 but I cant capture if the user will enter only a number eg 1 or 11 or any integer number with unknown number of digits.

Comment: Which version of regex are you using?

Comment: I want to use it as a pattern in a HTML input box I don't know the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex can be modified as

```
\d*([.,\/]?\d+)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lE9qR3/3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while testing this regexpr in regexr.com and in expresso software it doesn't capture the values I want.

Comment: @user3677132 I had a small typo in the answer. Corrected. Please see the edit

Comment: I checked it again and it worked. It doesn't although capture the .1 or ,1 but that's not mandatory for the project I create. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am happy with the first one no need to use the second one, you have got me covered. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short one that I think meets your needs:

```
\d?[.,\/]?\d+
```

The pattern is

\d? : one optional digit to match 1.1, 1/1 or 1,1. If 1111.1111 etc are valid, change to \d*

[.,/]? : an optional single period, comma or slash

\d+ : one or more digits.

reading "or a dot (...) and a number at the end", this might be more accurate (maybe you mean one and only one digit after the dot/slash/comma?)

```
\d*[.,\/]?\d
```

Which is

\d* : Any number of digits

[.,/]?: An optional delimiter

\d : **a single** digit

Answer (score 1):

If you are validating a user input on keypress or something,
you will need this form  `1,` too.

This should cover all the bases.

```
 #  ^(?:\d+(?:[.,/]\d*)?|[.,/]\d+)$

 ^ 
 (?:
      \d+                 # Forms 1 or 1, or 1,1
      (?: [.,/] \d* )?
   |                    # or,
      [.,/] \d+           # Form ,1 only
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d*(?:\.|\,|\/\d+)*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/21

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if the non-capturing group is needed, or whether that grouping needs to be greedy. I think it depends on whether `1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1` or similar would be part of the test data